# Python logging and Pydev debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, logging, configuration, pycharm

**Edit :**

Using Liclipse 1.2.1 instead of 1.3.0 or 1.4.0 is working fine. Changelog indicate both Pydev 3.9.1 and Eclipse 4.4.1 updates for 1.3.0. Seems to break logging debug.

---

Using Liclipse and Pydev debugger (and CPython) with the following code sample, getting that error :

```
 logging.config.dictConfig(config)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 794, in dictConfig
   dictConfigClass(config).configure()
 File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 576, in configure
   '%r: %s' % (name, e))
 ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': 'DictConfigurator' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

There is no problem without debugging, is the logging module require run environment and will only work on it ?

Here is the code sample used :

```
import logging.config
import yaml

def setup_logging():    
    default_path = 'logger.conf' 
    default_level = logging.DEBUG

    if os.path.exists(default_path):
        with open(default_path, 'rt') as f:
            config = yaml.load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=default_level)
```

And here is my logger.conf :

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False

formatters:
    simple:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    lineInfo:
        format: "%(asctime)s - Line: %(lineno)d - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: lineInfo
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
    debug_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: DEBUG            
        formatter: lineInfo
        filename: logs/debug.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 10
        encoding: utf8
    info_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: INFO            
        formatter: simple
        filename: logs/info.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 10
        encoding: utf8
    error_file_handler:
        class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
        level: ERROR            
        formatter: simple
        filename: logs/errors.log
        maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
        backupCount: 10
        encoding: utf8
root:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler, debug_file_handler]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

same problem with PyCharm.
possible workaround - to comment out pydev_monkey_qt.patch_qt() line in pycharm/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py, for Eclipse it should be located somewhere else

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked for me with PyCharm 4.0.5.

Comment: Thanks worked for me too...  with `Eclipse` and `Liclipse`
Eclipse Mars: /home/<user>/.p2/pool/plugins
Liclipse: /opt/liclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508181931/pysrc/pydevd.py

Answer (score 10):

There is now a relatively obscure (because they don't include the OP's error string in their webpage for good search indexing) fix implemented in PyCharm for this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/python-debugger.html

In PyCharm, go to:
File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Python Debugger

Then uncheck 'PyQt compatible'

Answer (score 1):

Ensure to import **PyQt4** before importing logging

Comment: Worked for me for PyQt5